# how to merge two different audio in video using java xuggler

Tags: java, audio, video, xuggler

I need help to concatenate two separate audio files together. My first audio track lasts for 7 seconds and I want my second audio track to play immediately after the first.

The following is my code:

```
private void initVideo(String fileName){
    String inputAudioFilePath = "/Users/Document/Desktop/audio.mp3";

    createEmptyMP4(folder + "/" + fileName + ".mp4");
    writer = makeWriter(folder + "/" + fileName + ".mp4");
    screenBounds = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4,screenBounds.width, screenBounds.height);
    startTime = System.nanoTime();

    IContainer containerAudio = IContainer.make();

    if(containerAudio.open(inputAudioFilePath, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cant find " + inputAudioFilePath);
    }

    // read audio file and create stream
    IStreamCoder coderAudio = containerAudio.getStream(0).getStreamCoder();

    if(coderAudio.open(null, null) < 0){
        throw new RuntimeException("Cant open audio coder");
    }

    IPacket packetaudio = IPacket.make();
    writer.addAudioStream(1, 0, coderAudio.getChannels(), coderAudio.getSampleRate());
    int a = -1;
    ArrayList<IAudioSamples> audioPac = new ArrayList<IAudioSamples>();

    while ((a = containerAudio.readNextPacket(packetaudio)) >= 0){
        if (a >= 0){
            // audio packet
            IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(512, coderAudio.getChannels(), IAudioSamples.Format.FMT_S32);
            coderAudio.decodeAudio(samples, packetaudio, 0);
            audioPac.add(samples);
        }
    }

    for(int j=0; j < 300; j++){ 
        writer.encodeAudio(1, audioPac.get(j)); 
    }

    coderAudio.close();
    containerAudio.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have opened two audio files:

coderAudio1 <--- first.mp3

coderAudio2 <--- second.mp3

write all your audio first samples into your **writer** and when it is finished, start writing the second audio samples.

With some changes and control, you can add your video frames in between of two audios.

Comment: thx for reply as u say i did but it is not working. it show error
15:14:23.932 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG com.xuggle.xuggler - Closing dangling Container (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:146)
15:14:23.932 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG com.xuggle.xuggler - Closing dangling StreamCoder (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:96)
Exception in Application start method

i did add 2 audio in arrayList like above code... but not woking.
It show same error.

 IStreamCoder coderAudio = containerAudio.getStream(0).getStreamCoder();

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code, but I get error on **big** files and I don't know the reason.

```
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;

/**
 *
 * @author Pasban
 */
public class xuggleMergeAudioTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IContainer countainer1 = IContainer.make();
        countainer1.open("audio.mp3", IContainer.Type.READ, null);
        IStreamCoder audio1 = countainer1.getStream(0).getStreamCoder();
        audio1.open(null, null);


        IContainer countainer2 = IContainer.make();
        countainer2.open("audio2.mp3", IContainer.Type.READ, null);
        IStreamCoder audio2 = countainer2.getStream(0).getStreamCoder();
        audio2.open(null, null);

        IMediaWriter mWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter("concatinated.mp3");
        mWriter.addAudioStream(0, 0, audio1.getChannels(), audio1.getSampleRate());

        IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
        while (countainer1.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0) {
            IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(512, audio1.getChannels(), IAudioSamples.Format.FMT_S32);
            audio1.decodeAudio(samples, packet, 0);
            mWriter.encodeAudio(0, samples);
        }

        while (countainer2.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0) {
            IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(512, audio2.getChannels(), IAudioSamples.Format.FMT_S32);
            audio2.decodeAudio(samples, packet, 0);
            mWriter.encodeAudio(0, samples);
        }

        mWriter.close();

    }
}
```

Also have you tried this demo from Xuggle:
https://code.google.com/p/xuggle/source/browse/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/ConcatenateAudioAndVideo.java?r=929

I think you have to check if channels and sample rates in both audios mach, too.

Comment: i have already work on this link you shared but no solution found... You only write audio1 channel...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta es una mejora, sirve para n archivos de audio

```
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IAudioSamples;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;

public class Concatenador_Audios {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcatenarAudios("D:\\out concatenate.mp3", "D:\\in Audio (1).mp3", "D:\\in Audio (2).mp3", "D:\\in Audio (3).mp3");
    }

    public static void ConcatenarAudios(String Ruta_AudioConcatenado,String... ruta_Audio) {
        int n = ruta_Audio.length;
        IMediaWriter mWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(Ruta_AudioConcatenado);

        IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            IContainer container = IContainer.make();
            container.open(ruta_Audio[i], IContainer.Type.READ, null);
            IStreamCoder audio = container.getStream(0).getStreamCoder();
            audio.open(null, null);
            if (i == 0) {
                mWriter.addAudioStream(0, 0, audio.getChannels(), audio.getSampleRate());
            }
            while (container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0) {
                IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(512, audio.getChannels(), IAudioSamples.Format.FMT_S32);
                audio.decodeAudio(samples, packet, 0);
                mWriter.encodeAudio(0, samples);
            }
            container.close();
            audio.close();
            }

            mWriter.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is an English-speaking site. If you can, please translate your content.